# How do i change elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, blackjack

I am making a program to emulate a game of blackjack. One thing i need to account for are the royal cards (king, queen etc.) For these the value should changed to be ten. I want the game to finely print that the dealer has either of these cards if they do, but i need to add a "score" but i cant sum a int with string object. I've tried solving this problem by introducing a for loop in the dealer function to replace every royal with the value 10, but when i return the "score", it seems as the values have not been changed because I get the error:

> line 22, in dealer
> score=cards[0]+cards[1]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

My code is under:

```
import random

deck=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'A','J','Q','K']*4

#Deal cards from deck
def deal(deck):
    cards=[]
    for i in range(2):
        cards.append(random.choice(deck))
    return cards

#Dealers hand
def dealer():
    cards=deal(deck)
    
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        royals=['J','Q','K']
        if i in royals:
            cards[i]=10
            score=cards[0]+cards[1]
        else:
            score=cards[0]+cards[1]
    

    return (f'Dealer has the cards {cards[0]} and ?', score)
```

Comment: Please post the full trace along with the error

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly on my end.

Comment: I think you forget to add 'A' in the royals list

Comment: No because A is supposed to have the value 11, not 10. The code doesnt work when the dealer gets a card that is J, Q or K.

Comment: Because when the dealer gets K and 5 for instance as a list (their hand of cards), the K is supposed to change to 10, to then be summed with 5 and the score should be 15, but K is not converted to a integer for some reason...

Comment: Just run the code multiple times, and you will see that it won't run if you have J,Q,K in the cards.

Comment: the code `cards.append(random.choice(deck))` may cause that `cards[0]` or `cards[1]` will contain a string  (A,J,Q,K) - this is the reason you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

> instead of using J ,Q ,K use number such as 11,12,13 respectively then it will add the score.

Comment: no, because J,Q,K is supposed to be formatted as J,Q,K in the print statement, but when summing it to store it as a "score" it should be an integer. And also J,Q,K i want them to be worth 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you're modifying `cards` out of scope. Try passing cards as an argument to the function and returning it. I could be wrong about that.

It seems to be like a better solution might be to put the value of the face cards in the list (1, 11, 12, 13) and then having doing something like  `+min(cards[i], 10)` with a special check for the ace.

I would also advise iterating over the list items directly instead of integer indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you evaluate score before checking if both cards are number. So you get an error when the last card is a letter.

```
def dealer():
    cards = deal(deck)

    for i in range(len(cards)):
        royals = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
        if cards[i] in royals:
            cards[i] = 10
        elif cards[i] == 'A':
            cards[i] = 11

    score = sum(cards)
    return (f'Dealer has the cards {cards[0]} and ?', score)
```

This is if you want to use the letters, it would be easier just using 11,12,13.

If you dont want to change the original list, this will be easier:

```
def dealer():
    cards = deal(deck)
    score = 0
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        royals = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
        if cards[i] in royals:
            score += 10
        elif cards[i] == 'A':
            score += 11
        else:
            score += cards[i]

    return (f'Dealer has the cards {cards[0]} and ?', score)
```